# extra layer of view everytime i go into a different UIcontrolview swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

This is the first one, normal with no problems
[image: This is the first one, normal with no problems]

There's an extra layer for everytime i go to a new view.
[image: There's an extra layer for everytime i go to a new view]

you could see it increases each time
[image: you could see it increases each time]

Whenever i go to a different view on xcode there's a layer that's the size of a toolbar that's blocking my view, i'm new to swift so I'm sorry if i don't use the proper terms but can anyone please help me with this issue?

this is the code that i use to switch views

```
    let register = UIStoryboard(name: "RegisterEmail", bundle: nil)
    let controller =register.instantiateViewController(identifier:"RegisterEmail") as! RegisterEmail 
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController:controller)
    self.view.addSubview(navigation.view)
    self.addChild(navigation)
    navigation.didMove(toParent: self)
```

edit(solved the problem) but

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ForgotPassword", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForgotPassword") as! ForgotPassword
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

doesn't work, any help?

Comment: Would you please try this line? `controller.view.addSubview(navigation.view)`

Comment: Added it but nothing happens, it stays on the same view and the on click for the button seems to be inexistent due to it but thnx for helping

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Is your project storyboard based? If so, could you please post a an image of the storyboard? Your problem is that you keep adding child VC one on top of each other.

Comment: swift based, i code my layouts

Comment: thanks for helping me figure out my problem

Comment: No problem. Why are you adding a new instance of a UINavigationcontroller to the current Viewcontroller?

Comment: Any way, later I will try to post an answer to your question

Comment: I'm new to this, so I'm watching tutorials to learn, I'm trying replicate an onclick listener for java on swift and that's what i found, but it seriously messed me up bad

Comment: Why you you creating new object of UIStoryboard? Please try above code to push ViewController. Eg:-   guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "RegisterViewController") as? RegisterViewController else {return}
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Comment: Set navigation.navigationBarHidden = true

Comment: Just posted the answer, BTW when answering to a comment, make sure to tag the user using @ so it gets notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the previous answer says, you keep adding a `UINavigationController` view to the view of your viewController. I believe you already added a `UINavigationController` to your storyboard, therefore, to grab it,  just use `self.navigationController`. You don't need to create a new one and add it to the viewStack. It is already presenting your current VC.
I can't understand what you want to achieve. If you want each view to have its own VC, then the code in the second code snippet should work - if you created three viewController in the storyboard. However, from the first code snippet, it looks like you want to add three child viewController. If this is the case, change the code snippet to

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ForgotPassword", bundle: nil)
let childVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForgotPassword") as! ForgotPassword
addChild(childVC) 
childVC.view.frame = frame
view.addSubview(childVC.view)
childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are adding a new navigation stack inside the current navigation stack, this should be why you have new navigation bar inside the view. You should only push or show the view.